# Python: how do i iterate over the first element of each sublist without knowing the number of sublists?

Tags: python

i have a list with multiple sublists.

```
l = [[a,b,c],[3,5,0],[3,1,0],...]  # I do not know how many sublists there are beforehand.
```

how can i iterate over the first item of each sublist?

```
e.g. a,3,3 then b,5,1 ...
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
for x,y,z... in zip(l[1],l[2],l[3]...) # "..." representing other sublists 
    do something with x,y,z... if condition...
```

Of course this won't work because I do not know how many sublists exist beforehand.

Ultimately, I want to filter the existing sublists if at the same index, all numerical values are equal to zero. For instance: c,0,0 would be removed (because all numbers are zeroes). But, a,3,3 and b,5,1 remain. At the end, I need 3 new filtered sublists to contain:

```
lnew = [[a,b],[3,5],[3,1]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

> `zip()` in conjunction with the `*` operator can be used to unzip a list

```
>>> lis = [['a','b','c'],[3,5,0],[3,1,0]] 
>>> for x,y,z in zip(*lis):
    print x,y,z
...     
a 3 3
b 5 1
c 0 0
```

> I want to filter the existing sublists if at the same index, all
>   numerical values are equal to zero

```
>>> zipp = [x for x in zip(*lis) if any(y != 0 for y in x \
                                             if isinstance (y,(int,float)) ) ]
>>> zip(*zipp)
[('a', 'b'), (3, 5), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: You need to use a tuple instead of `x, y, z` since OP doesn't know how many elements are in `lis`.

Comment: I think the Ashwini had it right before x was changed to x,y,z.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
from numbers import Number
lis = [['a','b','c'],[3,5,0],[3,1,0]] 
print [list(el) for el in zip(*[el for el in zip(*lis) 
       if any(i for i in el if isinstance(i, Number))])]
# [['a', 'b'], [3, 5], [3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Eh, the answers here seem to be good, but i'll offer an alternative:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [3, 5, 0], [3, 1, 0]]
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        do_whatever(l[i][0])
        i += 1

    except IndexError:
        break
```

I realize that its not as elegant as the other solutions, but its nice to have a variety to choose from!

And this also still works if you're still adding to the list as you iterate through it!